# how to set run arguments for python when using wing IDE?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, wing-ide

how to set run arguments for python when using wing IDE?

```
D:\TEST\djgprj
├─.idea
├─testdjgprj.wpr
├─testdjgprj.wpu
└─testdjg
    ├─.idea
    ├─testdjg
    ├─manage.py
    ├─static
    └─templates
```

I create a project using wingIDE, and save to folder `D:\TEST\djgprj`, but the `models`, `manage.py`, programs are in folder `D:\TEST\djgprj\testdjg`. 
When I try to run manage.py using wingIDE, I dont know where to set arguments. I know there is one place which is `Debug->Run Arguments`, but it does not work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the file (either in editor or Project tool) and select Properties and set the run args under Debug > Run Arguments.

If you mean sending arguments to Python itself and not your code, this is the Debug > Python Options property instead (the default is -u for unbuffered output).

Comment: Yes, I got it. and I have changed `Configure External Console`, and I can see the debug info on external console. Tks, Wingware.